# Read a .dat data file in R based on a SAS script

Tags: r, sas

I need to access CDC's immunization data for my research project but could not figure out how to open the .dat files on their website. I am pulling the datasets from: https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nis/data_files.htm

I have been trying to use the `SAScii` package. This is the error message that I have been getting:

```
read.SAScii("https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/nis/nispuf14.dat", "https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/nis/nispuf14.sas", zipped = F)

Error in sub(substr(SASinput[i], slash_asterisk[1], asterisk_slash[1] +  : 
  zero-length pattern
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to get these datasets to be in a more user-friendly format? Thank you!

Comment: These data files come paired with an R script - have you tried using that to import the data?

Comment: At the top of that SAScode you see: `LIBNAME PUF "path-to-output";
OPTIONS FMTSEARCH = (PUF WORK LIBRARY); %LET flatfile = "path-to-file\NISPUF14.dat";` so it seems you may need to do some editing to get the locations of the data and code files to be congruent.

Comment: @lotus Yeah I have tried with the R script multiple times. I don't have a background in stats so I'm just not doing something right haha. The error I'm getting with the R script when I do this `Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/nis/nispuf10.dat/NISPUF10.RDataFALSE', probable reason 'No such file or directory`

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks. I tried doing `flatfile <- "https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/nis/nispuf14.dat"` first before typing in my original code but that still didn't work :(

Comment: What I meant was use a browser to download the data and modify the script so that it referred to the local data file.

Comment: R code is here, but this question should be closed. https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/nis/nispuf14.r